# Chrome DevConsole - No longer able to copy element as text

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

This is frustrating me to no end: something's apparently changed(?) with Chrome's Developer console, where it doesn't seem to allow you to copy an element as text.  For example:

```
document.getElementsById('myid')
```

returns:

```
<body id="myid" class="someclass">..</body>
```

And I want to literally copy the above.

I want to select it with my mouse, hit ctrl-c, and have the line above, as it appears, to paste somewhere.  This has been the behavior of the dev console until "now", with Chrome 87.

Now, you can't select as text (not holding down 'alt', not any way). If you right click to copy, you can "Copy Outerhtml" or "Copy element" neither of which I want. In the latter case, that gives (in this instance) EVERYTHING under . (Same with doing copy())

The only work-around *appears to be* to edit as html (which only works if the page is still valid) and copy manually. Or, to actually copy the whole element and then delete everything. This is insane!

Does anyone have a work-around? Can someone point me to the changelog when this was implemented and/or a relevant bug report? Google is unfriendly trying to search for this, which is why I've broken down to ask here.

Replication:

- Open Chrome Developer Console -- here, on Stackoverflow
- Do: `$('body')[0]`
- Try to copy `<body class="ask-page unified-theme theme-dark js-ask-page-v2 floating-content">..</body>` as text.
  FAILS.

Comment: Weird. I've never wanted to do this and would have considered the behavior you wanted a bug. I'd expect to copy the outerHtml

Comment: If you don't mind using a different browser, still works in firefox (tested on 85)

Comment: I've done it frequently; often to paste quickly in chat the outcome of a command (expected return).  Here, in particular, this was looking at what was returned by $('someid'), which happened to be <body>, with other relevant information (classes). I wanted to just dump that as a comment; I'm certain this used to be possible, to highlight output in the console and paste it. Am I crazy??? Is this Mandela effect?

Comment: "Copy Selected" in Safari works as you described.

Comment: Will: There's no ability to do so here: That's the issue! You literally cannot select the line to copy it. The mouse turns to circle with a slash through it. Given I'm working with a Chrome extension, on Windows,, it's not really an option to go to FF or Safari. I'm more curious if others have noticed this, and if there's a workaround. It seems "Copy selected" worked as recently as Chrome 82, but I'm feeling like I'm crazy now because I can't say for sure.

Comment: Drag the preview (the thing you want to copy) into the input line in console.

Comment: @wOxxOm: You're a beautiful human being. Can you suggest that as the answer, so I can mark it? 

It's not quite as easy as just dragging mouse and ctrl-c, but compared to anything else (like copying the element and deleting) it's a valid work-around. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag the preview (the thing you want to copy) into the input line in console:

[image]

Note, the `body` tag cannot be dragged, apparently.